# Android boolean is not keeping its state

Tags: android, runnable

So, I have a boolean called `nuanceWaiting` it's initially set to `true`.  I immediate run a runnable loop that checks if nuanceWaiting is true or false.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    nuanceWaiting = true;
    ...
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    ....
    soundMeterLoop();
}
public void soundMeterLoop() {
    soundMeterHandler = new Handler();
    soundMeterRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(nuanceWaiting) {
                //do my stuff
                amplitude = soundMeter.getAmplitude();
                if (amplitude > threshold) {
                    decibelLevelOutput.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    startNuance();
                } else {
                    decibelLevelOutput.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }
            soundMeterHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
    soundMeterHandler.postDelayed(soundMeterRunnable, 100);
}
public void startNuance() {
    nuanceWaiting = false;
    nuance.toggleReco();
}
public void stopNuance() {
    Log.d("SpeechKit", "stopNuance");
    nuanceWaiting = true;
    Log.d("SpeechKit", "nuanceWaiting " + nuanceWaiting);
}
```

Now, for some reason, once I call false, now, `nuance.toggleReco()` goes to another class and when it's finished, it calls `stopNuance();`

`nuanceWaiting` becomes false (showing in the second log), but when I check a log in the runnable, it still says true and never "stays" false when running the runnable again.  Any idea as to why it doesn't stick to being false?

Below is what `nuance.toggleReco();` does

```
public void toggleReco() {
    Log.d("SpeechKit", "In "+state);
    switch (state) {
        case IDLE:
            recognize();
            break;
        case LISTENING:
            stopRecording();
            break;
        case PROCESSING:
            cancel();
            break;
    }
}
```

It's usually in the `IDLE` state, so I'll follow that method,

```
private void recognize() {
    //Setup our ASR transaction options.
    Transaction.Options options = new Transaction.Options();
    options.setRecognitionType(RecognitionType.DICTATION);
    options.setDetection(DetectionType.Short);
    options.setLanguage(new Language("eng-USA"));
    options.setEarcons(startEarcon, stopEarcon, errorEarcon, cancelEarcon);

    //Start listening
    recoTransaction = session.recognize(options, recoListener);
}

private Transaction.Listener recoListener = new Transaction.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onStartedRecording(Transaction transaction) {
        Log.d("SpeechKit", "onStartedRecording");
        //We have started recording the users voice.
        //We should update our state and start polling their volume.
        state = State.LISTENING;
        startAudioLevelPoll();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishedRecording(Transaction transaction) {
        Log.d("SpeechKit", "onFinishedRecording");
        //We have finished recording the users voice.
        //We should update our state and stop polling their volume.
        state = State.PROCESSING;
        stopAudioLevelPoll();
        avatar.stopNuance();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRecognition(Transaction transaction, Recognition recognition) {
        //We have received a transcription of the users voice from the server.
        state = State.IDLE;
        Log.d("SpeechKit", "onRecognition: " + recognition.getText());
        voiceRecognizeText = recognition.getText();
        voiceRecognize = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.voiceRecognize);
        voiceRecognize.setText(voiceRecognizeText);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Transaction transaction, String s) {
        Log.d("SpeechKit", "onSuccess");
        //Notification of a successful transaction. Nothing to do here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Transaction transaction, String s, TransactionException e) {
        Log.e("SpeechKit", "onError: " + e.getMessage() + ". " + s);
        //Something went wrong. Ensure that your credentials are correct.
        //The user could also be offline, so be sure to handle this case appropriately.
        //We will simply reset to the idle state.
        state = State.IDLE;
        avatar.stopNuance();
    }
};
```

Comment: you set it to true in stopNuance, but you say _"but never "stays" false"_ what do you mean?

Comment: @Blundell In the other class, I make it go back to `stopNuance()`, then `nuanceWaiting` turns true, but in the runnable, it just says false

Comment: it goes false because in `startNuance()` you set it to false. This is multi-threaded code :-)  don't trust the order you read logs or what you _think_ the order of the code is. Your thread may call "`run()`" again a second time before or after toggleReco completes - therefore setting it back to false

Comment: @Blundell, wow, I need to re-read "how to ask an appropriate question".  I have more conditionals in that runnable, let me update my code a bit

Comment: @Blundell, I've updated the code to show _when_ `startNuance()` is being called. It's called when the audio level in the microphone hits a certain threshold.

Comment: still what I said could happen could happen: `soundMeterRunnable` is ran, `startNuance()` is called, 100 ms passes, `startNuance()` is called again, in the mean time the first time calls `stopNuance()` but then the second  `startNuance()` completes setting `nuanceWaiting` back to `false`. Make the delay longer between re-running the runnable and see if your problem persists

Comment: @Blundell, Thank you, I just tried upping it to 500 and 1000 respectively, though nothing is changing.  But you bring up some good points.  I have a little more testing to do

Comment: @Blundell It's not multi-threaded unless `nuance.toggleReco()` starts another thread.

Comment: Instead of using a `boolean` you could try removing the runnable callbacks where you used to set it to false, and resume them where you used to set it to true

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede yeah, i was more thinking of the main thread and this `soundMeterHandler`

Comment: @Blundell, I feel like I'm going to need to give my whole code to get the question answered because of everything I'm using.  I tried using `soundMeterHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(soundMeterRunnable);` to stop the runnable, but then I get an issue with the recorder (two methods trying to use the same recorder), which for some reason is handled the other way

Comment: @Blundell This `Handler` would run tasks in the main thread.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede ah right yeah sorry because of the constructor used

Comment: maybe show us what `nuance.toggleReco();` actually does for some context

Comment: Note that `soundMeterHandler` is initialized in `soundMeterLoop()`, which is called from `onStart()`, which could be called more than once, thus creating more than one `Handler`, and leaving you no reference to the original one by which to cancel callbacks.  Off the top of my head, I'm not sure what happens if you orphan a `Handler` like that.  (I.e., whether the `Looper` or something else still has a reference to it, or if it gets GCed.)

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede great info, thank you.  Would putting it in onCreate be better for this?

Comment: @Blundell, Added a bit of the Nuance stuff - I call `stopNuance()` in the `onFinishedRecording` method

Comment: Yes.  Or you could initialize it where it's declared: `private final Handler soundMeterHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, I've just tried this, but it seems to act the same for now - obviously that's not the fix, but I will keep that in mind.  Blundell, I have put a bunch of logs in and it seems that the runnable doesn't really stop.  It continues one more time after I try to kill it and I think this is the problem

Comment: yeah I've read about that, I think you can call stop passing `null` which stops ALL callbacks but might not work in your situation.

@KevinKrumwiede I think it appears this code is multi-threaded because it calls `stopNuance()` from the `recoListener` which seems to be some type of callback that I imagine is happening asynchronously

Comment: @Blundell, I've figured a way to kill the loop (and it's basically just don't make it loop if the condition fails).  I've asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403513/android-nullpointerexception-in-runnable-for-the-second-time that might shed more light on this problem if you're still interested.