# Android NullPointerException in Runnable for the second time

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm sure this error is because I don't fully understand threads, but here it goes...

I have a runnable that is started when `onCreate()` is called within a method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Set all app specific starting points here
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_avatar);
    ...
    soundMeterLoop();
}  

public void soundMeterLoop() {
    Log.d("SpeechKit", "Start Sound Meter");
    soundMeterHandler = new Handler();
    soundMeterRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!soundMeter.SoundMeterRunning) {
                Log.d("SpeechKit", "Start SoundMeter in the runnable");
                startSoundMeter();
            }
            if (soundMeter.mMediaRecorder != null) {
                amplitude = soundMeter.getAmplitude();
                decibelLevelOutput.setText("" + amplitude);
                if (amplitude > threshold) {
                    decibelLevelOutput.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    Log.d("SpeechKit", "Interrupt and run startNuance()");
                    startNuance();
                } else {
                    decibelLevelOutput.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    Log.d("SpeechKit", "Running");
                    soundMeterHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                }
            }

        }
    };
    soundMeterHandler.postDelayed(soundMeterRunnable, 100);
}
```

This runs just fine when it's created in the `onCreate`. As you can see, it kills itself (by not renewing the loop if the statement fails) and runs `startNuance()`.

```
public void startNuance() {
    soundMeterHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(soundMeterRunnable);
    nuance.toggleReco();
}
```

I then kill the runnable and start a method in another class.  This class runs fine, then when it's finished doing its thing, I call back to this main class with `avatar.stopNuance();`

This is in the Nuance.java class

```
    @Override
    public void onFinishedRecording(Transaction transaction) {
        Log.d("SpeechKit", "onFinishedRecording");
        //We have finished recording the users voice.
        //We should update our state and stop polling their volume.
        state = State.PROCESSING;
        stopAudioLevelPoll();
        avatar.stopNuance();  // <<<<<
    }
```

It then returns back to my main activity (`avatar`) and runs this `stopNuance()` method:

```
public void stopNuance() {
    Log.d("SpeechKit", "stopNuance(), start loop again");
    soundMeterLoop();
}
```

Then it tries to run the same loop from before.  Only this time, I'm getting a lot of errors that pertain to nullpointerexceptions.  specifically starting with `decibelLevelOutput.setText("" + amplitude);`

I'm not sure why these things are null or how to fix them.  Is this because it started a new thread that was not started in the creation of the runnable?

Comment: what is the type of the variable `nuance`? i would also rename `avatar` to `avatarActivity` so it is more obvious what you are communicating with

Comment: `nuance` is referencing the class `Nuance`.  That's a good call on the avatarActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking on chat the actual issue was elsewhere in the codebase.

The problem was this:

```
public class Nuance {

      private Activity activity;
      private Session session;
      public Avatar avatarActivity = new Avatar(); // DONT DO THIS

 ....

         @Override
         public void onFinishedRecording(Transaction transaction) {
             Log.d("SpeechKit", "onFinishedRecording");
             //We have finished recording the users voice.
              //We should update our state and stop polling their volume.
              state = State.PROCESSING;
              stopAudioLevelPoll();
             avatarActivity.stopNuance();
          }
```

You should never, ever ever create your own instance of an Activity. They are creted and managed by the system. The system will call the lifecycle methods on the instance (`onCreate` etc) but if you create an instance these methods are not called - therefore a lot of strange behaviour happens.

The fix here is this:

```
public class Nuance {

      private Avatar activity;
      private Session session;

 ....

         @Override
         public void onFinishedRecording(Transaction transaction) {
             Log.d("SpeechKit", "onFinishedRecording");
             //We have finished recording the users voice.
              //We should update our state and stop polling their volume.
              state = State.PROCESSING;
              stopAudioLevelPoll();
              activity.stopNuance();
          }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this!  You saved me probably days of research!  Thank you for the lesson as well.  Learning every day!

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to create a new runnable everytime `soundMeterLoop()` is called.

Try this:

```
private final Handler soundMeterHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Set all app specific starting points here
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_avatar);
    ...
    soundMeterLoop();
}  

public void soundMeterLoop() {
    Log.d("SpeechKit", "Start Sound Meter");
    soundMeterHandler.postDelayed(soundMeterRunnable, 100);
}

private final Runnable soundMeterRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!soundMeter.SoundMeterRunning) {
                Log.d("SpeechKit", "Start SoundMeter in the runnable");
                startSoundMeter();
            }
            if (soundMeter.mMediaRecorder != null) {
                amplitude = soundMeter.getAmplitude();
                decibelLevelOutput.setText("" + amplitude);
                if (amplitude > threshold) {
                    decibelLevelOutput.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    Log.d("SpeechKit", "Interrupt and run startNuance()");
                    startNuance();
                } else {
                    decibelLevelOutput.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    Log.d("SpeechKit", "Running");
                    soundMeterHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: @ntgCleaner I really want to get this working now! haha

Comment: I'm getting a `RuntimeException` saying `Unable to start activity` and also `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method`. stemming from the `soundMeterHandler.postDelayed(soundMeterRunnable, 100);`  I don't have a handler established, I assume

Comment: did you see i moved the handler up above `onCreate` and made it final

Comment: Woops, must've scrolled too fast!  I added in a `new Handler()` after I commented and it didn't seem to work, then added the `final` to it, which still doesn;t seem to work, but now it's because of a different problem.  The `decibelLevelOutput` is null!  I have it instantiated in the class, then I have it initialized in the `onCreate` before the loop

Comment: so this makes me think your example is quite like your real code :-) in the example I expect all the views (`decibelLevelOutput`) to be instantiated before you call `soundMeterLoop()` (which in the example is the last line of `onCreate`)

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake, I was testing and put the initialization of `decibelLevelOutput` in the runner and commented out the init line in `onCreate`.  I fixed that, the app starts, runs, but when I kill it and try to bring it back, I get the same `nullPointerException` error on the same line of `decibelLeveloutput`

Comment: if `decibelLeveloutput` is null, i think your code is doing something the example is not :-) `decibelLeveloutput` is a view in the Activity as long as that Activity is around then this should not be null (unless something else has changed the layout). If you are doing something crazy and this Activity moves into the background or is destroyed then you call the public method `soundMeterLoop()` on the activity then this types of things will happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131938/discussion-between-ntgcleaner-and-blundell).